# How do I show time on the x-axis in Flot?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, flot

I am trying to graph with Flot some data over time. The data being graphed contains:

```
time: unix epoch time (whole seconds since 1/1/1970)  
value: it varies but it's always an integer between 0 and 10000
```

The `time` values can be in intervals of 5, 60 or 3600 seconds.

How do I coerce Flot into drawing me graphs where it shows the time on the x-axis:

- in seconds if the interval is 5 seconds - there would be 10mins of data
- in minutes if the interval is 60 seconds - there would be 1 hour of data
- in hours if the interval is 3600 seconds - there would be 24 hours of data

I have tried working with the `axis.tickSize` option but I am completely stumped.

I'm using Flot 0.6 and jQuery 1.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...stupid me didn't realise that time had to be in milliseconds.

This is a pretty good example of how to deal with time:

> [Flot Examples - Monthly mean atmospheric CO2 in PPM at Mauna Loa, Hawaii](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/time.html)

And of course our own Stack Overflow reputation graphs.